# pip now installs to python3 not python 2.7.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I have Linux mint 18.x installed. When i ran pip initially it installed packages to python 2.7.x. I also installed pip3 and it handled python3 package install. But after I followed some instructions for other reasons and did apt-get update / upgrade, pip now installs to python3 and not 2.7.x. How can I reset please  as I use both. Is it a matter of rerunning:

sudo python pip.py?

Comment: Does `python -V` print Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Check `which pip` if this is pointing to correct version. If not modify `$PATH`  variable in shell accordingly

Comment: You can ensure that you use the right pip (and that it installs stuff in the right place), by calling the pip _module_ instead of using the pip executable directly. Eg, `python3 -m pip -V` will print the version info for the `pip` associated with Python 3.

Comment: `python2.7 -m pip` is guaranteed to run the module installed into your `python2.7` module path.

Answer (score 3):

Try `pip2` instead of `pip`.For Example:
`Pip2 install ..`..

Answer (score 1):

Check for the version of  your python that you want to install your modules in:

```
python -V
```

Then you can use the following:

```
pip3.6 install <package> # This is for python 3.6
```

Example for python 2.7

```
pip2.7 install <package>
```

**or** for those of you using macports make sure your version match using.

```
port select --list pip
```

then change to the same python version you are using.

```
sudo port select --set pip pip27
```

Comment: Sorry for the belated reply, been busier than a fish salesman at an otter gathering. Thanks to all those that made the effort and the time to reply. :-)